# subversion excluding specific files

Tags: svn

How do we exclude files which follows some pattern like I want to skip hidden files ( starting with . e.g. .vmalloc.o.cmd or .mmap.o.cmd ), there are so many files which can be figured out using regex, but can not be specified one by one.
 So whenever I commit I don't want those files to sent to server.

EDIt: Do I have to do svn propset svn:ignore *.cmd in each directory ? If there is not such way ( for all directory) then why it's not there ?

Comment: Do you have `.svnignore` files? Are they the source of the problem?

Comment: they are not. But I though there should be some way. What will be the problem of having such solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use RegEx, but wildcards should do the job nicely:

```
svn propset --recursive svn:ignore .vmalloc.o.cmd*
```

Run this on the top-level directly. Caveat: folders added after you run this command will not inherit the ignore. (So make sure to re-run the command every time you add a new folder.)

Comment: Do i have to do this for individual directory manually ? or it will be set for all sub-directories ?

Comment: Kind of. There's a recursive option, but it's not continual.

Answer (score 1):

svn:ignore property uses 3 types of filter:
?,*,[]

You can not specify regexp

more info here : http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html